# How can I change the id of an SQL query automatically via PHP?

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a news website, and when I create a new article, the title/text are registered on the database. The articles are in a dynamic PHP page with header/footer, with the text itself being called from the database . On the index there is a list with links to every article, and I want those links to change the id automatically.

index.php

```
<?php include "header.php"; session_start();?>
<?php include "slideshow.php"; ?>
<?php include "db.php"; ?>

    <br>

    <table class="table_index">

        <?php

            while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                echo '<tr><td class="td_tit"><a href="example_article.php" >'.$line["title_article"].'</a></td></tr>';

                echo '<tr><td class="td_subt"><a href="example_article.php" >'.$line["subtitle_article"].'</a></td></tr>';

                $_SESSION['id_article'] = $line["id_tb_article"];

            }

        ?>

    </table>

<?php include "footer.php"; ?>
```

example_article.php

```
<?php

    session_start();

    include "header.php";

        $id_article = $_SESSION['id_article'];

        $query = "SELECT title_article, subtitle_article, content_article FROM tb_article WHERE id_tb_article = $id_article";

        $conn = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:3307', 'root', '', 'article') or die("error");

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<div class='titlediv'><h1 class='title'>" . $row["title_article"]. "</h1></div><div class='titlediv'><h3 class='title'>". $row["subtitle_article"]. "</h3></div><div class='textdiv'><p class='text'>" . $row["content_article"]. "</p></div><br>";
        }

        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }

    include "footer.php";

?>
```

Comment: You're trying to pass the `$id_article` as a Session variable. This will not work like intended. If I understand you correct you want to provide links to different articles. However your code reassigns `$_SESSION['id_article']` in every while iteration in index.php. What you should do is use a link with a special styling class and pass the article id as a get or post parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use session parameters for this task. Instead use get parameters (or post) here is a little example. Also your code is vulnerable to SQL-Injection, but thats your problem :D

Index.php rewrite your while loop like this

```
while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo '<tr><td class="td_tit"><a href="example_article.php?id=' . $line["id_tb_article"] . '">'.$line["title_article"].'</a></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td class="td_subt"><a href="example_article.php?id=' . $line["id_tb_article"] . '">'.$line["subtitle_article"].'</a></td></tr>';
}
```

then fetch the id in example_article.php like this:

```
$id_article = $_GET['id_article'];
```